# openldap -- exclude specific attributes from replication

Tags: ldap, openldap, replication

I have two openldap servers replicating `cn=config` with `syncrepl` in a provider-consumer relationship.  There are a few attributes that I would like to exclude from replication.

I see that `syncrepl` has an `exattrs=<attr list>` option, but I cannot find any documentation as to how to set it.  For example,

- Are the attributes comma-delimited, or colon-delimited, or something else?
- Are wildcards allowed, or do I have to list all of the attributes by hand?  As it turns out, all of the attributes I want to exclude begin with `olcTLS` .  Can I set `exattrs=olcTLS*` ?

Answer (score 2):

They are comma-separated. About that I am sure, look the following snipet from a production server:

```
 olcSyncrepl: {0}rid=006 provider=ldap://ldap.example.org bindmethod=sasl sa
 slmech=EXTERNAL searchbase="ou=people,dc=example,dc=org" type=refreshOnly  int
 erval=00:00:05:00 retry="5 5 30 +" timeout=1 scope=sub schemachecking=on star
 ttls=yes tls_cert=/etc/ssl/certs/client.example.org.pem tls_key=/etc/ssl/pri
 vate/client.example.org.key tls_cacert=/etc/ssl/certs/DigiCertCA.crt exattrs
 =sambaNTPassword,userPassword
```

About wilcards, I would guess no, it's not possible. I tried naively as you suggested and slapd refused to start.